# ParsleyJS never detects success

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui, parsley.js

I posted a similar message previously regarding a different javascript/jquery form validation library. A bunch of people said that library I was using was too old so I decided to switch to Parsley. I was able to get a little further with parsley but it still doesn't work as intended. If you notice when you submit the form initially the class gets changed on the select but after the select changes the success class never gets added to the select and the error is never cleared. Does anyone know why the error class is not being replaced with the success class once the form is populated?

I made a jsfiddle, I noticed the code snippet wasn't working. https://jsfiddle.net/1wxsbaq4/

```
 <html>

  <head>
<style>
input.parsley-success,
select.parsley-success,
textarea.parsley-success {
  color: #468847;
  background-color: #DFF0D8;
  border: 1px solid #D6E9C6;
}

input.parsley-error,
select.parsley-error,
textarea.parsley-error {
  color: #B94A48;
  background-color: #F2DEDE;
  border: 1px solid #EED3D7;
}

.parsley-errors-list {
  margin: 2px 0 3px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  opacity: 0;

  transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.parsley-errors-list.filled {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/components/dropdown.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/components/transition.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.8.0/parsley.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/components/dropdown.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/components/transition.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.blockUI/2.70/jquery.blockUI.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        $('#identifier').dropdown();
        $('#ticketform').parsley();
  });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br/>
    <br/>
                        <form id="ticketform" name="ticketform" action="open_ticket.php" method="post">

    <div class="container">
        <div class = "row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
                        <p>Please select or enter an IP address:</p>
                </div>
                <div class ="col-md-4">  
                <select name="identifier" class="ui search selection dropdown" id="identifier" data-parsley-errors-container="#select-errors" required="">  
                        <option value="">Please enter or select IP address</option>
                        <option value="4.4.4.4">4.4.4.4</option>
                        <option value="8.8.8.8">8.8.8.8</option>
                </select>
                </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="select-errors"/>
`       </div>
        </div>
      <div class = "row">
        <div class = "col-md-4">
                <input id="button" type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Submit ticket" class="uibutton normal">
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
                </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bad interaction between Parsley and the dropdown library you are using.

Probably because the dropdown library you are using does not respect the specs and does not trigger an `input` event after it's been modified?